# c# windows form application game

Tags: c#

I need to make a game with a moving object from point a to b.
I am connected to a database with a table that contains an x and y colum.
I have the sql database in an datatable but i dont know how to get the rows to the location of the picturebox.

Here is my code. It is all I have:

```
        MySqlConnection conn =
        new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=programeren;Uid=root;Pwd=;");

        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "select * from vrachtwagen1";
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dtData = new DataTable();
        dtData.Load(reader);
        conn.Close();
```

Comment: Are you asking how to iterate through the data table? If you need specific rows in vrachtwagen1 then you'll need to tell us the table structure and column names.

Comment: i need to get the x and y coordinates from my database to move my picturebox. table name structure is an x and y column and only ints in it

Answer (score 0):

```
int x;
int y;

DataTable dtData = new DataTable();
dtData.Load(reader);
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    x = dt.Rows[0]["x"];
    y = dt.Rows[0]["y"];
}
```

This assumes the columns in your table are called 'x' and 'y' and there is only one row of data. If there are more rows you'll need to narrow down your query to return one row.